# Probabilistic interpretation of Hausdroff measure

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

My problem is to find/derive a pdf in terms of a parameter which closely resembles Hausdroff measure and the idea stems from the following concepts. Please correct me where I go wrong.

[Paper1 - Estimating Fractal Dimension by Theiler](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~phylabs/adv/ReprintsPDF/NLD%20Reprints/16%20-%20Estimating%20Fractal%20Dimension.pdf) - This paper talks about various ways to calculate the dimension of a data set - correlation dimension, box counting dimension, fractal dimension using various methods. Eq(12) mentions a relation $bulk=size^{dimension}$ where size can be a measure such as volume, entropy, and size is the distance. I have labelled this measure $bulk$ as $\theta$.

Eq(19) defines a measure $\Gamma$ which is the $D-$ dimensional volume. and $D$ over here is he embedding dimension. Looking at this definition and simplifying it appears that $\Gamma = \sum_i \Gamma_i$ where $\Gamma_i = r^D$.

Another  method of estimating the fractal dimension is Takens' Maximum Likelihood estimation mentioned in details In Chapter 5 the Master Thesis [Paper2-The identification of strange attractors using experimental time series](http://rullf2.xs4all.nl/nsag/msct.pdf) which I have explained below.

Considering a sample that consists of $N$ i.i.d distances $r$. The pdf in terms of $r$ is $f(r) = D*r^{D-1}$ and $\theta = r^D$ (From Eq(12) of Paper1).

Hausdroff measure is a scalar parameter like the fractal dimension $D$. If from above Papers, it is possible to include the term $D$ in a distribution, then I was wondering if there is any relation by which I  can derive a density function in terms of the measure. Any ideas will be really helpful.

Q1: Is $\theta$ -- the Hausdroff measure a random variable since $\theta = r^D$ where $r$ is a random variable and $\theta$ is a function of $r$. ?

Q2: If $\theta$ is a random variable then how to find the pdf? How to find a pdf in terms of the parameter of interest $\theta$.  Please help.